# Which BIONICLE set did this mask came from?

Tags: piece-information, bionicle

I just unearthed a rather wealthy stash of semi-rare Great Kanohi masks. Never knew I collected them! Anyway, among them was this clear transparent [Kaukau (Great Mask of Water Breathing)](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Kaukau):

[image]

You may recognize this mask in transparent blue as worn by [Toa Gali](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Gali#Toa_Mata) and some Ga-Matoran (notably [Hahli](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Hahli#Mata_Nui)) on Mata Nui.

But what stumps me about this mask is the fact that it's not blue; it's *colorless*. I've looked in [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/32571) but it doesn't list this as one of the colors it occurred in.

Does anyone know which BIONICLE set this mask may have come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>I found the answer while I was writing this question, but I'm posting question and answer just for dibs on the [bionicle](/questions/tagged/bionicle) tag ;)</sup>

---

The Peeron page for that mask I just linked to lists the part number as **32571**. I do a search for the part number, and come across the [Brickipedia page for that part](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Part_32571). Scrolling down, I find the source:

> **Transparent:**
>
> - [8525 Masks](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/8525_Masks) (random)
> - [8530 Masks](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/8530_Masks) (random)

Apparently, I found this mask along with the numerous bronze and silver Great Kanohi masks in one of those mask packs.

Fun fact: this colorless Kaukau was designed to be wearable by Toa Kopaka, and possibly also the Ko-Matoran. The Toa is known to have had this mask equipped in [BIONICLE Chronicles 1: Tale of the Toa](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/BIONICLE_Chronicles_1:_Tale_of_the_Toa), but it's not entirely clear if this is part of the canon. There aren't any named Ko-Matoran with this mask as far as I know.

Comment: Feel free to keep custody of the tag all by yourself :-)